# Problems with Textbook width

Tags: asp.net, textbox, formview

It seems to me that this should not be this difficult but I have tried a dozen solutions and none seem to work.

I am building an insert form within a form view control. I have set up several of the elements within a table to give it a cleaner look. The table is 3 rows by 4 columns. In the last row, the first cell has some simple text and I have used a columnspan attribute to combine the other three cells into one and placed a textbox within that cell.

I want the textbox to fill the combined cell width-wise. No matter what I try, it will not expand to fill the space available. I have tried CSS and every attribute I can find but so far have had no luck. I would appreciate any insight anyone could provide.

The table code is:

`<asp:Table HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" CellPadding="3">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right">Date of Exam:</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="pes_DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pes_Date") %>' /></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;USDA ID Tag:</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="pes_USDA_TagIDTextBox" runat="server"  DataSourceID="GetTags" DataTextField="an_USDA_TagID" DataValueField="an_USDA_TagID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("pes_USDA_TagID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Please select USDA Tag ID..." Value="" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" Height="30" VerticalAlign="Bottom">Veterinarian:</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Bottom"><asp:TextBox ID="pes_VetTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pes_Vet") %>' /></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Bottom">Exam Weight:</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Bottom"><asp:TextBox ID="pes_Exam_WeightTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pes_Exam_Weight") %>' /></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell Height="50" VerticalAlign="Bottom">Other ID Markings:</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Bottom" Columnspan="3" HorizontalAlign="Left"><asp:TextBox ID="pes_ID_MarkingsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pes_ID_Markings")%>' Width="100%" />
        </asp:TableCell>
   </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>`

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Would you be able to put together an example with the generated html? It's hard to help troubleshoot with just the .net markup, we don't have the same variables to bind to and whatnot

Comment: You have a cellpadding of 3 on your table.  if cellpadding is not 0, there's no way your textbox will ever take up 100% of the white space in the cell.  It will take up 100% of the assigned space, then add the padding all around the contents of the cell.